# Position of line number in `\equation` environment with `\split`

Tags: spacing, equations, align, split

I am trying to position the equation number at the last line of my multiline equation that I write using `equation` and `split` environment.

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:1}
    \begin{split}
        a &\leq b\\
        & \leq c \\
        & = d \\
        & \leq e \\
        &= f,
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

The above gives the following

[image]

But I want the equation number `(E.2)` where the multiline ends, which is after `=f,`. How can I do this? I know how to do this using `\notag` in `\align` environment but `\align` environment puts too much vertical space before the equation which I want to avoid.

Comment: Load `amsmath` with the `tbtags` option.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `align` or `aligned` with a `[b]`. Needless to say that labels like `eq:1` defeat the purpose.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
        a &\leq b\notag\\
        & \leq c \notag\\
        & = d \notag\\
        & \leq e \notag\\
        &= f,\label{eq:1}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
        a &\leq b\\
        & \leq c \\
        & = d \\
        & \leq e \\
        &= f,\label{eq:2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\documentclass[tbtags]{...}` moves the equation number to the bottom when numbers are on the right, so in that case, `split` would work.  Of course, that applies to the entire document.